# Trying to read the contents of a file into an array, but the contents are separated by a colon

Tags: java

Inside my file is the two-letter abbreviation of each state followed by the full name of the state, and each state abbreviation and name is separated by a colon.

Like this:

al:Alabama

ak:Alaska

I need to read this into an array of 52x2 and I am not sure how to do that. The code I have now just reads each line from the file into the array without separating the abbreviation and name.

```
String[][] states = new String[52][2];

while (input2.hasNext()) {
    for (int row = 0; row < states.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < states[row].length; column++) {
            states[row][column] = input2.next();
            System.out.printf("%s%n", states[row][column]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should write a class to represent your state-abbreviation combination, for example: `class State { String name; String abbreviation; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code(Comments inline):

```
String[][] states = new String[52][2];

int row = 0;

while (input2.hasNext()) {
    
    // Read whole line from the file
    String line = input2.nextLine();
    
    // Split string into tokens with : character.
    // It means, Line: al:Alabama is converted to
    // ["al", "Alabama"] in tokens
    String tokens[] = line.split(":");
    
    // Store first token in first column and similarly for second.
    states[row][0] = tokens[0];
    states[row][1] = tokens[1];
    
    row++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the predefined `split()` `String` function:

```
// A string variable.
String myString = "Hello:World";
// split the string by the colon.
String[] myStringArray = myString.split(":");
// print the first element of the array.
System.out.println(myStringArray[0]);
// print the second element of the array.
System.out.println(myStringArray[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As your data also adheres to the [.properties format](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s0204propertiesfileformat01.html), you can use the [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class.

```
Path file = Paths.get("...");
Properties properties = new Properties(52); // Initial capacity.
properties.load(Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));

properties.list(System.out);
String name = properties.get("AR", "Arabia?");
```

Here I used an overloaded `get` where one can provide a default (`"Arabia?"`) in case of failure.

Answer (score 0):

This one line version makes use of NIO `Files` to load from file and converts the contents in a stream:

```
String[][] states = Files.readAllLines(Path.of("states.cfg")).stream().map(s -> s.split(":", 2)).toArray(String[][]::new);
```